# When try to update the object, HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class BookRisk extends CustomerBaseEntity<BookRisk, BookRiskDTO> {

    private String bookRiskData;
    private OffsetDateTime externalQueryDate;

    @OneToOne
    private Cafe cafe;
```

BookRisk bookRisk = bookRiskDataRepository.findByCafeId(cafe.getId());

```
        if (bookRisk == null) {

            return bookRiskDataRepository.save(
new BookRisk(bookRiskData, getExternalQueryDate(bookRiskData), cafe)).getId();

        } else {
                return bookRiskDataRepository.save(
bookRisk.modifyBookRisk(bookRisk, request.getBookRiskData(),
                        getExternalQueryDate(bookRiskData))).getId();
            }
        }
```

Here, i want to create a new `BookRİskData` object if it is not saved before. It not, i want to set values from request and save again to update.

For update, it creates another object and then it gives error:

```
HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException : Object of class BooktRisk] with identifier [8]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : BookRisk#8] (Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) :
```

i thought it is because at first i use

```
findByCafeId
```

then i make

```
save
```

but i am not sure about it.

The update method:

```
 public BookRisk modifyBookRisk(BookRisk bookRisk, String bookRiskData, OffsetDateTime externalQueryDate) {

        bookRisk.setExternalQueryDate(externalQueryDate);
        bookRisk.setBookRiskData(bookRiskData);
        return bookRisk;
    }
```

I dont change `version` or `id`. When it saves for second time, it increases version also.

And it has another id ofcourse.

can it be because of `cafe`?

COnstructor:

```
      public BookRisk(String bookRiskData, OffsetDateTime externalQueryDate, Cafe cafe) {
                 this.createStamp = EntityActivityDateTimeStamp.fromContext();
            this.modifyStamp = createStamp.copy();
            this.bookRiskData = bookRiskData;
            this.externalQueryDate = externalQueryDate;
            this.cafe = cafe;

;
    }

    public BookRisk() {
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add BookRisk constructor logic?

Comment: I dont think it  you are calling it here new BookRisk(bookRiskData, getExternalQueryDate(bookRiskData), cafe) with those parameters..

Comment: Could you please add the constructor logic that you are using ?

Comment: @JonathanJohx added bottom of question